Is this web-site a Z-Library site that was seized by the FBI?
Z-Library is a file-sharing site for books. It is illegal in many jurisdictions, and has had some domains seized by the FBI in 2022.
zlibrary-bl.se [web archive version] is ostensibly one of those seized domains. However, ban message appears to be poorly formatted and potentially of a comical nature. I question its validity.



Was this domain seized by the FBI?

Reminder: Sorry, we don't care about your political opinions.

In November 2022, the United States requested the arrest of the two of Z-library promoters, the Russians Anton Napolsky and Valeriia Ermakova, in Argentina. Opposing their extradition, the latter had obtained house arrest in Cordoba. But they escaped, as revealed in May 2024 by the Argentine daily La Voz del Interior. They have been on the run ever since (source).

In what way do you believe it might be poorly formatted? I can't seem to see the problem, but English isn't my mother tongue.

@Clockwork can't precisely tell you either but it really looks like something from a movie or that some graphic design student whipped up in 3 minutes. The "LOOK HOW THEY SPEND YOUR MONEY!" also has a really comical vibe if you are in any way informed about the moral backgrounds of the modern day copyright-piracy debate

Yes. The top level domain nameserver for .se redirects a lookup request to a DOJ controlled server, ns1.seizedservers.com.

ns1.seizedservers.com 151.201.135.115 AUTH 20 ms Received 1 Answers, rcode=NO_ERROR  zlibrary-bl.se. 86400 IN A 151.201.135.114

This server is explicitly named in other DOJ filings for domain forfeiture:

Take all reasonable measures to redirect the SUBJECT DOMAIN NAME to
substitute servers controlled by Homeland Security Investigations, by changing the
authoritative name servers to any new authoritative name server or IP address to be
designated by a law enforcement agent in writing, including e-mail, to the Subject
Registry. Specifically, upon seizure of the Subject Domain Names, the Subject
Registry shall point the Subject Domain Names to the IPR Center’s Domain Names
ns1.seizedservers.com (IP address 66.212.148.117) and ns2.seizedservers.com (IP
address 66.212.148.118).


Please give a reference to the first claim. (It seems to depend which DNS server you use?!)

It does not depend on which DNS server you use if you see the same webpage. dig SOA +trace zlibrary-bl.se should resolve through the same authority chain no matter what, even if you're running your own DNS server. There's no 'reference' I can link for that.

Added reference to online command, rather than platform-specific command result.

It would be nice to add the command to the answer itself so that all the comments can be deleted.

I'm not gonna lie, I did not expect this. Literally nothing about this page aside from the logos says "official notice". The "this is how they are spending it" at the bottom is boulevard-level trash.

@Oddthinking the only DNS servers that wouldn't follow the DNS records given by the official Swedish nameservers would be those that have been explicitly configured to ignore those records, which no self respecting DNS operator would do.

WHOIS can also be used to determine the registration information for a domain, including the authoritative name servers for it. Here is a public WHOIS lookup for zlibrary-bl.se. (It agrees with the answer, showing ns1 and ns2.seizedservers.com as the nameservers.)

@jwenting: This is what I mean.. Not all servers seem to have that info.

Whois is not the same as DNS. There's no guarantee that the whois on a domain points to anything valid. A DNS lookup tool does not usually query whois records.

@xLeitix it really looks like what some youtuber in 2010 would've whipped up in a parody clip on copyright enforcement lol.
